# existence of eigenfunctions in non-self adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

> Remark: The existence of eigenfunctions is only guaranteed for self-adjoint operators.

How does one justify this statement? An operator not being self-adjoint makes it not have eigenpairs?

Comment: If may not have, yes. Not a necessity, it just can happen sometimes. For example. In the space $\ell^2$ of square summable sequences, the operator $S(x_0,x_1,...)=(0,x_0,x_1,...)$ doesn't have any eigenvectors. Observe that if $r(x_0,x_1,...)=(0,x_0,x_1,...)$, then either $r=0$, in which case also $0=x_0=x_1=...$ or $r\neq0$ and also $0=x_0=x_1=...$.

Comment: There are also self-adjoint operators which have no eigenfunctions.  For instance, on $L^2([0,1])$, consider $(Tf)(x) = x f(x)$.  Maybe there are some extra assumptions in what you are reading (e.g. a compact operator).